# How to put values into hash and retrieve

Tags: ruby, hash

Hi I want put these values into hash and also retrieve them.

```
  c={}

  a={"cat"=> 1,"cap"=> 2} 

  b={"rat"=> 12,"soap"=> 5}
```

Now how can I put values "a" and "b" into value "c"?

And retrieve these values a and b from value c?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't "push into" hashes. See the [documentation for `Hash`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't push into a hash.

Every value that you add into a hash has to have a key. So in your case, you can do

```
c[key1] = a
c[key2] = b
```

Your hash now becomes `c = {"key1" => {"cat" => 1,"cap" => 2}, "key2" => {"rat" => 12,"soap" => 5}}`

You can retrieve them by `c[your_key]`.